# Single Sign On with Cakephp

Tags: mysql, session, cakephp, single-sign-on

I'm working on a bunch of cakephp apps that are all services that you have access to when you login to the main website.  Each app will be hosted on a separate server, and there will be a separate login server as well.

Doing the research, I found Cakephp supports writing sessions to a database, http://blog.jambura.com/2011/08/24/should-i-use-database-for-storing-sessions-in-cakephp/

And also it supports having multiple database connections, 
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mithesh/2008/09/02/talking-to-multiple-databases-from-single-cakephp-application

So I was considering the possibility of storing the sessions on the login server, which the other websites all access, and then they all use their own databases for the rest of their data.  It seems like it would be simple to implement, but I have concern that there would be too much reading and writing on the login server's database.  Is there a way to optimize for this?  Or should I do another approach entirely?

Comment: I think the title should be "Sharing sessions between multiple Cake apps", rather than Single Sign On. It's what you're trying to accomplish, but not really what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Try check [useDbConfig property of model](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-Model.html#%24useDbConfig). Think, that it will be simpler if your sessions and users tables will be on the same database, then you will common user database and sessions. So, you will not require to implement SSO.